# Mod rewrite for replicated wordpress site

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to direct all traffic to the homepage only to a php script called go.php that gets a variable from the URL.

If someone visits domain.com/username go.php gets the username, looks up their information, saves the information to a session and then redirects to index.php and displays a modified version of the homepage (same domain) that has the retrieved information. Everything works except the mod rewrite part.

I tried the following and am not sure what I am doing wrong:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/$ go.php?id=$1 [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

My logic was that if a request is to index.php it should be allowed, to prevent looping.

If the request is to the homepage it will go to go.php?id=username and the that script will redirect to index.php and trigger the prior mod rewrite rule to prevent looping.

Otherwise, it will do the regular redirect to index.php if the directory or filename doesn't exist.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you mean:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ go.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

---

*Explanation:*

I'm looking at the `^/$` in the regular expression in the `go.php` rewrite rule. I've tested that and it appears to be an impossible match in that situation. One might be wanting to capture requests for root. But the forward slash is not passed to this portion of the `RewriteRule` for root. so a call for root (only) is `^$`. And there's also no capturing parenthesis to feed the `$1` you have appended to `go.php?id=$1`.

Comment: Yes, that works perfect by itself. But,I'm not sure how to make it work with the existing WordPress rules.

Comment: After making that change, what errors or undesired result do you get?

Comment: "This webpage has a redirect loop"
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ go.php?id=$1 [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /test/index.php [L]
</IfModule>


"The page isn't redirecting properly"
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ go.php?id=$1 [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /test/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: Both of those were when requesting the homepage without the username.

Comment: So you get server errors when navigating to something like: `domain.com/`. I set up something similar on my computer with your rewrite script and it's working fine with and without username. What redirect code are you using in *go.php*? PHP `header` function?

Comment: Yes, header ("Location: index.php");

Comment: What happens if you remove the last rule set? (The last 3 lines.)

Comment: Same thing as before, so apparently those aren't part of the issue.

Comment: Are you using RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] or RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php$ for your test?

Comment: Before I was using `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php$`. Now I changed it to `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]` to test and that worked too. Both at the same time worked too.

Comment: Do you have another computer or server you can run a test on? I suggest stripping down to bare bones and adding one step at a time, testing along the way.

Comment: Yes, I got it to work! But, then I realized I had no way to first check if a page were valid before checking against usernames. I wound up leaving the .htaccess alone and creating custom code for WordPress that runs if there is a 404 error. Thank you so much for your help. It was a great learning experience.